# How can I handle the "Before you continue to Google" popup in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing some python to open a Chrome browser, type "Wikipedia" and search for it, however my code is always blocked because of the the Chrome "Before you continue to Google" iframe, and my code doesn't seem to correctly bypass this. Are there any methods to bypass this or resolve my issue to select "Accept all cookies" (as it only shows when I'm using my bot, instead of normal manual use). Here is the code I currently have:

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import time
    
    # Create a browser instance (you need to have the appropriate driver executable)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Replace with the appropriate driver (e.g., Firefox)
    
    try:
        # Open the Google search page
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/?client=safari")
    
        # Wait for the search input field to be visible
        search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))
        )
    
        # Handle the "Before you continue to Google" popup
        try:
            # Wait for the popup to appear
            popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "introAgreeButton"))
    
            )
            
            # try to close the iframe by clicking the agree button  
            driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]"))
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span').click()
    
            # Click the "I agree" button to accept cookies
            popup.click()
        except:
            pass  # No popup found or accepted, continue
    
        # Find the search input field by name and enter "Wikipedia"
        search_input.send_keys("Wikipedia")
        search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # Press Enter to perform the search
    
        # Wait for the search results to load
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Wikipedia"))
    
        # Now you can continue with your existing code to interact with the elements on the page
    
        # For example, you can wait for an element to be present
        my_lists_selector = ".my-lists-download"
        my_lists_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, my_lists_selector))
        )
    
        # Wait for another element to be present
        download_selector = ".download-buttons > .dk-btn__primary"
        download_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, download_selector))
        )
    
        # Click on the element with the CSS selector ".download-buttons > .dk-btn__primary"
        download_element.click()
    
    finally:
        # Close the browser window
        time.sleep(10)  # This will wait for 10 seconds before closing the browser
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of the inside `try` block when you know the pop-up always appears. Just click on the <kbd>Accept all</kbd> button before you perform other actions as shown in below code.

Refer the code below:

```
# Open the Google search page
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/?client=safari")

# below line will click on Accept all button of the pop-up 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Accept all']").click()

# Wait for the search input field to be visible
search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))
)

# Find the search input field by name and enter "Wikipedia"
search_input.send_keys("Wikipedia")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # Press Enter to perform the search
```

Comment: Thank you, marked as the accepted answer.